# Clear previous search result in search controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I initiate search after a user enter 3 characters in search bar with following command. It works properly.

```
if searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count > 2 { ... }
```

But, if user delete the search text that entered before and write another one, the table view starts to display previous results until search text reaches 3 characters.
So, how can I clear previous appended search results from memory ?

Comment: When user press backspace on that time you just set nil in your result array.

Comment: Add else statement and set result array to nil.

Comment: Richard, how can I check press backspace or click on clear button ?